# Discord bot not coming online, basically tutorial code

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

Just trying to get this bot to come online so I can confirm where I'm at, but apparently I am doing something wrong. To clarify, the bottom console is what is output, but the bot remains offline in the discord, with the greyed-out circle and it stays in the user list section "offline".

Program class code following. It doesn't produce any errors in the editor or upon execution/during runtime. The bot in my server has not yet come online. The code is basically identical to the discordnet.dev guide, except for some minor changes https://discordnet.dev/guides/getting_started/first-bot.html

I have confirmed the token is correct, it's an old application so I just generated a new token for it. Used the universal platform console app template in visual studio, running windows 10.

```
using Discord;
using Discord.WebSocket;

using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text;

namespace Mai
{
    class Program
    {
        private DiscordSocketClient _client;
        private Dictionary<string, string> _config;

        static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        public async Task MainAsync()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mai, starting up!");
            await LoadConfigurationFile();

            Console.WriteLine("Okay, I'm making my client now! I'll also add the logger to it!");
            _client = new DiscordSocketClient(
                new DiscordSocketConfig()
                {
                    LogLevel = LogSeverity.Debug
                }
            );
            _client.Log += Log;

            Console.WriteLine("Logging in and starting the client!");
            await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, _config["Token"]);
            await _client.StartAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("I'm all set up! I'll keep working until the console is closed!");
            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }

        # region Methods

        public Task Log(LogMessage msg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msg.ToString());
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        } // End of method Log

        public Task LoadConfigurationFile()
        {
            using (FileStream openStream = File.OpenRead("config.json"))
            {
                _config = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<String, String>>(openStream);
            };
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        } // End of method LoadConfigurationFile

        #endregion Methods

    } // End of class program

} // End of namespace Mai
```

And the console looks like this:
[image: Console output]

Comment: What exactly do you mean the bot isn't coming online. The logs you posted show that the bot successfully connected to 3 guilds and it's ready.

Comment: @Anu6is the bot does not come online in Discord. The bot's online icon is grey, and it stays in the user list section that is offline.